# Playing Warzone 2100: Latest version under Xenial?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, updates, games

Xenial Xerus ships with version 3.1.1 of the great game Warzone 2100. A new version has just been released:

> 2016-07-10 After 3.5 years of development, version 3.2.0 of  Warzone
>   has finally been released. [Website...](http://wz2100.net/)

**Addit:** And now [Version 3.2.1 is also out](https://wz2100.net/news/warzone-2100-321-is-now-released/)!

How do I get the latest version under Xenial?

Comment: The link to the website is broken, it should be http://wz2100.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few *relatively* easy steps are required to get the very latest version of Warzone 2100 and run it under Xenial Xerus:

**1. Activate the Source Repositories:**

Follow this path to activate software sources:

```
Dash > Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software > Source Code
```

After clicking on 'Source Code' allow the repositories to reload.

**2. Download the dependencies:**

We use both the dependencies for the older Warzone 2100 package as well as *some extras* required by the newer version:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep warzone2100 
sudo apt-get install checkinstall qt5-default qtscript5-dev libsdl2-dev libssl-dev
```

**3. Download, compile, package and install:**

The following *single* command will look after the rest of the installation, simply copy and paste the whole command into a Terminal window:

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/warzone_build && cd ~/Desktop/warzone_build && \
wget http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/warzone2100/releases/\
3.2.1/warzone2100-3.2.1.tar.xz && \
tar xvf warzone2100-3.2.1.tar.xz && cd warzone2100-3.2.1 && \
./configure && make -j 4 && \
sudo checkinstall --pakdir "$HOME/Desktop/warzone_build" \
     --backup=no --deldoc=yes --pkgname warzone2100 --pkgversion 3.2.1 \
     --fstrans=no --deldesc=yes --delspec=yes --default
```

You may need to log out and then log back in before Dash *sees* the game but otherwise we are done :).

Unless of course you want some intro and 'cut-scene' movies for the game:

**3. Optional: Install the movies:**

There are some nice, high quality movies to download that integrate nicely with the game. *Note that the high quality set is a reasonable download at 965MB*.

First create the download folder if it does not already exist:

```
mkdir ~/.warzone2100-3.2.1
```

Then grab the high quality compressed movie files with the following *single command*:

```
cd ~/.warzone2100-3.2.1 && \
wget http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/warzone2100/\
warzone2100/Videos/high-quality-en/sequences.wz
```

And now we are really done!

**4. Enjoy the game:**

A screenshot of Warzone 2100 on my own Xenial installation:

[image]

**References:**

- [Warzone 2100: Linux Compile Guide](http://developer.wz2100.net/wiki/CompileGuideLinux)
- [Warzone 2100: Movie details](https://sourceforge.net/projects/warzone2100/files/warzone2100/Videos/high-quality-en/)

Answer (score 3):

Here latest compiled Warzone2100 (actually v3.2.1) for Ubuntu 16.04.x:

http://www.playdeb.net/app/Warzone2100

Direct download (*):
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/getdeb_games/xenial/games/getdeb/warzone2100

(*) Before download/install from getdeb, open terminal (Ctrl + Alt + T) and execute these commands:

wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb games" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'