# I have extracted the tar warzone2100-0.2.1 but don't know how to install

Tags: compiling

Here's all the files that I extracted

```
data folder
lib folder
makerules folder
src folder
AUTHORS file
CHANGELOG file
config.guess file
config.h.in file
config.log file
config.sub file
configure file
COPYING
decomp
install-sh file
Makefile file
Makefile.in file
missing file
README file
```

Using ubuntu 16.10

Comment: I downloaded it at http://download.gna.org/warzone/releases/0.2/warzone2100-0.2.1.tar.bz2

Comment: There is a question and answer that should help you here: http://askubuntu.com/q/798106/57576 This is for the latest release: 3.2.1, I am not sure why you are after an older release?

Comment: I have recently found it at download.gna.org/warzone

Comment: Try the linked mini guide and you should be up and running :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need help installing warzone 2100-0.2.1](http://askubuntu.com/questions/851752/i-need-help-installing-warzone-2100-0-2-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read the `README` file (`less README`). Follow the instructions contained in the `README`. Make sure you have installed any requirements specified in the `README`. Then, it's simple (check for errors at each step, fix errors before proceeding):

```
./configure
make
make check
make test
# The previous 2 make commands may fail with "No rule to make target"
# then the install command from the README
# I've previously installed the installwatch package, so I would
sudo installwatch --logfile=installwatch.log make install
```

Comment: I've cheacked the readme but this is all i have found

Comment: I checked but no requirements